# Stack of cards effect: Change zIndex to highest of all similar divs when dragging

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, z-index

I'm trying to put a div on top of all the similar divs using `z-index` when start dragging. My attempt is kinda working, but when clicking on a the other div of the 3, that one doesn't go on top but stays under.

```
// Handle start moving
const handleMoveStart = () => {
    const currentIndex = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(card).getPropertyValue('z-index'))
    const popupsAmount = document.querySelectorAll('.playingcard').length
    index = currentIndex + popupsAmount + 1
}
```

A GIF might be more clear:

[image]

How to always put a div on top of the "pile" when dragging it, no matter how many I have?

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like you are only incrementing the z-index.  If you click on one card multiple times you would have to click on the other cards the same number of times to catch them up.
In a three card example I would go the opposite direction and have the z-index start in one of 3 states for all cards 0 - 2. Initialize all three cards z-index with a unique number and when a card is clicked make it z-index = 2 and decrement the others if not 0.

Edit: The reason I attempted this was because I had a similar z-index problem at work myself and I had to do quite a bit of looking to figure out my issue.  I am not clever enough to refine it anymore than this:
https://jsfiddle.net/damussel06/gkso24va/168/

```
const cardZero = document.getElementById("cardZero");
const cardOne = document.getElementById("cardOne");
const cardTwo = document.getElementById("cardTwo");


$(document).ready(function() {

  // z-index initalize  
  cardZero.style.zIndex = 1;
  cardZero.innerHTML = cardZero.style.zIndex;

  cardOne.style.zIndex = 2;
  cardOne.innerHTML = cardOne.style.zIndex;

  cardTwo.style.zIndex = 3;
  cardTwo.innerHTML = cardTwo.style.zIndex;
})



function cardOnTop(c) {

  /* clicked card gets z=index of 3 */
  topCard = document.getElementById(c);

  /* if top card is already on top do nothing */
  if (topCard.style.zIndex != 3) {

    /* set cards */
    switch (c) {
      case 'cardZero':
        // fix cards one and two
        if (cardZero.style.zIndex == 1) {
          cardOne.style.zIndex--;
          cardTwo.style.zIndex--;
        } else {
          cardOne.style.zIndex = 1;
          cardTwo.style.zIndex = 2;
        }
        // set picked cardZero
        cardZero.style.zIndex = 3;
        break;

      case 'cardOne':
        // fix cards zero and two
        if (cardOne.style.zIndex == 1) {
          cardZero.style.zIndex--;
          cardTwo.style.zIndex--;
        } else {
          cardZero.style.zIndex = 1;
          cardTwo.style.zIndex = 2;
        }
        // set picked cardOne
        cardOne.style.zIndex = 3;
        break;

      case 'cardTwo':
        // fix cards zero and one
        if (cardTwo.style.zIndex == 1) {
          cardZero.style.zIndex--;
          cardOne.style.zIndex--;
        } else {
          cardZero.style.zIndex = 1;
          cardOne.style.zIndex = 2;
        }
        // set picked cardTwo
        cardTwo.style.zIndex = 3;
        break;

      default:
        cardTable.innerHTML = 'error !';
    }


    /* displays new style.z-index on card */
    cardZero.innerHTML = cardZero.style.zIndex;
    cardOne.innerHTML = cardOne.style.zIndex;
    cardTwo.innerHTML = cardTwo.style.zIndex;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's interesting, wouldn't have thought of that, and yes you're right about the current behavior - it's not ideal. Would you have an example on how to implement that? Kinda tricky to figure it out code wise.